# Prestashop 1.7.6: Getting and displaying the 2° product image as background in text customization area

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am on prestashop 1.7.6. On the product page: i need to show the second(2°) or third(3°) image as `background-image` in the `textarea` text customization (when text customization is active).

[example image getting first product image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9FIS.png)
In the photo attached i get the first image but i don't know how to get the second one.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method in Product.php class, to get the images:

```
 public static function getImagesByID($id_product, $limit = 2){
    $id_image = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT `id_image` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` WHERE `id_product` = '.(int)($id_product) . ' ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1, ' . $limit);
    $toReturn = array();
    if(!$id_image)
       return;
    else
       foreach($id_image as $image)
          $toReturn[] = $id_product . '-' . $image['id_image'];
    return $toReturn;
}
```

And use the static function in the  smarty template

```
{assign var="pImages" value=Product::geImagesByID($product.id_product, 2)}
{foreach from=$pImages item=image name=images}
   <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $image, 'home_default')}" {if $smarty.foreach.images.first}class="current img_{$smarty.foreach.images.index}"{else} class="img_{$smarty.foreach.images.index}" style="display:none;"{/if} alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if}/>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a misspelled in the smarty code.

Try to insert this code to the smarty template

`{assign var="pImages" value=Product::getImagesByID($product.id_product, 2)}
{foreach from=$pImages item=image name=images}
    <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $image, 'home_default')}">
{/foreach} `
Tested on PS1.7.6